# HTML Table --> Selecting 1 Column to Filter in a Multi-Column Table

Tags: html, filter, html-table, multiple-columns

I want to perform an HTML table search on one column of a table. The table in this example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/1166/) shows 2 columns. I have added classes to the  tags to select column "Title 1" to filter only - however, the code is still looking at the "Title 2" column for the filter.

```
var $rows = $('#table tbody tr td[class = "col1"]');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).hide();
});
```

Could anyone provide some advice to the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem of your code is that when you do `hide()`, you're hiding out the `<td>` instead of the `<tr>` so that you end up searching `col2` when the `<td>` of `col1` is hidden. So, in that regard you need to use the parent `<tr>` and hide it.

```
 }).parent("tr").hide();
```

Another problem i saw is that your `$row` is good initially but once you
hide at least a row you end up with less rows to work with. So, in that regard you
need to preserve the original number of rows and use it to hide those that need to be hidden and show those need to be shown.

See my updated [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/1169/)

Comment: This answer is still filtering the second column.

Comment: You want to filter only the first column? While showing both the first column and second columns of the rows that are filtered?

Comment: Could you explain briefly this statement: $("tr:hidden").show()? Why is this statement before the .filter line? The code works, I am just not sure why "tr:hidden" is there when the rows are still visible. If you would help me figure out what I am not understanding, I would be very appreciative. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2134003 the tr:hidden is to show or unhide all hidden rows if there is/are row(s) that is/are hidden. So, that everytime you keyup or search you will have a new set of hidden rows via the filter.

Answer (score 0):

As per the OPs comments.

I think you're running into trouble because your selector is too detailed. try:

```
var $rows = $(".col1", "table");
```

Comment: The problem is that even though I am selecting the first column, the code is filtering both columns when I only want one filtered.